# Rails - route index to first module's object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Say I have a module name Server that was created with a scaffold. I want the url 'www.example.com/server/' to be redirected to the first Server object that exists. So for example to be redirected to 'www.example.com/server/2'.

How could this be done with routes.rb (or any other way)?

route.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :servers
end
```

Server controller:

```
class ServersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_server, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /servers
  # GET /servers.json
  def index
    @servers = Server.all
  end

....
```

Comment: So you are saying that whenever the user tries to open the index page of server, it should redirect him to the first server object right?

Comment: yes the index page of servers to the first object

Comment: your can put `redirect_to servers_path(Server.first) and return` inside your index method

Comment: Minato thanks! used: redirect_to server_path(Server.first) and return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your can put

```
redirect_to server_path(Server.first) and return
```

inside your `index` method it'll redirect you when ever index action is called.

and just to extent [@richfisher's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4571024/richfisher) answer (which might be a more appropriate way to do it.)

```
resources :servers, except: [:index] # this won't generate redundant routes
get '/servers/' => 'servers#first' #note this is now accessible via "server_path" instead of "servers_path" helper.
```

Comment: change servers_path to server_path

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I'd do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :servers, except: :index do
   get "", action: :show, id: Server.first.id, on: :collection
end
```

This will allow you to use the `show` action in place of `index` in a super efficient setup:

```
#app/controllers/servers_controller.rb
class ServersController < ApplicationController
   def show
       @server = Server.find params[:id]
   end
end
```